# Creating Teams in Multiplayer Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

so I am creating a Squad PvP game, where 2 squads get spawned into an arena. Anybody has an idea on how to create a team Selector. Or a tutorial? Or a step by step way to do it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Photon PUN2](https://www.photonengine.com/pun) supports multiplayer syncing & voice chat. There's a learning curve, but it's fun. Good luck!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen im trying to create a team selector

Comment: Photon supports a lobby with varied options. How much did you implement so far in terms of multiplayer?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen up until now, i have followed Dapper Dino's tutorial from episode 1 youtu.be/gxUCMOlISeQ to episode 3 youtu.be/5QuCtbaI-ag where 2 players can spawn after queuing